# how to send json post in cakephp

Tags: json, api, cakephp, post, outbound

I need to send exactly this:

```
POST http://api.outbound.io/api/v1/identify
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "api_key": "MY_API_KEY",
 "user_id": "MY_UNIQUE_USER_ID",
 "traits" : {
    "email" : "dhruv@outbound.io",
    "name" : "Dhruv Mehta",
    "phone" : "650xxxyyyyy"
 }
}
```

i never did something like this and i've made a lot of research but i couldn't find how to send those parameters to that URL

i hope you guys can help me with an example please, best regards!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a lot of research, i find out how to do it...

1.- Use

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http'); // you should put this on your controller
```

2.- this on your function

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```

3.- Here comes the data you want to send via POST (in this example i will use the variables i've used.. you can replace them, add more or delete some.. it depends on the info you want to send)

```
$data = array(
           "api_key" => "API KEY",
           "user_id" => $idUser,
           "event" => "other",
           "extra" => array(
                          "course" => $course,
                          "price"=> $price )
               );
```

3.- You set the Headers

```
$request = array(
        'header' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),
    );
```

4.-json_encode it

```
 $data = json_encode($data);
```

5.- Where are you sending the Post To?, which data?, type of request?, do it this way

```
$response = $HttpSocket->post('http://api.yourweburl.com/api/', $data, $request);
```

*.- You can see the response uncommenting this snippet

```
//pr($response->body());
```

*.- Finally if you want to redirect somewhere after everything is done.. do it this way...

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

You should have something like this.

```
public function actiontooutbound($idUser, $course, $price){
 $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();

    $data = array(
           "api_key" => "API KEY",
           "user_id" => $idUser,
           "event" => "other",
           "extra" => array(
                          "course" => $course,
                          "price"=> $price )
               );

    $request = array(
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),
    );
    $data = json_encode($data);
    $response = $HttpSocket->post('http://api.outbound.io/api/v1/track', $data, $request);
   // pr($data);
    //pr($response->body());
   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

}

This is how you call this function from another function (just in case)

```
$this->actiontooutbound($idUser, $course, $price);
```

if you have any questions let me now i'll be happy to help you ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this in PHP, I'd use curl.  The following is untested, so no guarantees that it's correct:

```
$json = array(
    'api_key' => 'My_API_KEY',
    'user_id' => 'MY_UNIQUE_USER_ID',
    'traits' => array(
          'email' =< 'dhruv@outbound.io',
          'name' => 'Dhrub Mehta',
          'phone' => '650xxxyyyyy'
     )
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.outbound.io/api/v1/identify');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$results = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    debug(curl_error($ch));
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
}

return $results;
```